# Why is "back" used here even though it is the first action?

Tags: meaning, grammar

[I knew I must reach the body for the key, so I raised the lid, and laid it **back** against the wall.](http://www.literature.org/authors/stoker-bram/dracula/chapter-04.html)

This is the first time he has laid the lid against the wall, but why is *back* used here?

Answer (score 2):

The lid is resting against the wall here, the narrator is probably not the first person to have placed it in that position.

However, this is the term 'lean back' rather than just 'laid'. It gives the impression that it's being supported by the wall. More info:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lean+back

Comment: Yes. This _back_ is _at the back_ not _back in its original position_.

Comment: @user4550 Correct. It's more like "I put it at the back of the table."

Comment: Not quite. It's more 'I put it back against the gatepost', which shows it's leaning against something.

Comment: @JeffSahol I wouldn't think it's that either. More along the lines of 'I put it back against the table leg'. :)

Comment: Exactly. It's not back to where it was, but back against something.

Comment: "So this "back" doesn't suggest moving it to the original position?" ...correct. It is not "expressing a return to an earlier or normal condition." The other usages (including mine, @Ronan Murphy) have to do with its position in space "toward the rear; in the opposite direction from the one that one is facing or traveling."

Comment: Jeff's isn't a wrong answer, he's offering a different alternative example. That isn't the correct use of a flag.

Comment: "the narrator is probably not the first person to have placed it in that position" - This is just to show that you can place back something that someone else has placed before, but not something that you have placed there before.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same meaning.